# Image displaying error from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3

After the recent changes in my application still i get this issue while displaying the image using the relative path in the database. `Error: 404 NOT FOUND  http://localhost:1256/Empdet/%22/Photos/jobs.jpg%22`

[image: Screenshot]

**Controller.js:**

```
 $scope.UploadFile = function () {
    console.log('UploadFile');
    console.log($scope.Empdet.PhotoFile);
    var file = $scope.Empdet.PhotoFile;
    console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));
    var uploadUrl = "../Photos";
    console.log('before file upload');
    EmployeeFactory.UploadFile(file, uploadUrl).success(function (response)  {
        $scope.Empdet.PhotoText = response;
        console.log('$scope.Empdet.PhotoText');
        console.log(response);
    }).error(function () {
        console.log('error');
    });
    console.log('after file upload');
};
```

**service.js:**

```
service.UploadFile = function (file, uploadUrl) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    return $http.post('/Empdet/UploadFile', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    });
}
```

**EmpdetController.cs:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile()
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Photos/"), file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        // prepare a relative path to be stored in the database and used to display later on.
        var filename = Url.Content("~/Photos/" + file.FileName);
        // save to db
        return Json(filename.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: try removing the second / from `"~/Photos/"` ?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire Which will give you /PhotosFileName ? I don't think this is the answer.. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @Frankline I think you have some extra quotes(") in your URL which the browser translates to %22, If this was not your intention, there is your problem.

Comment: @Billy i know that billy `(")` is my problem how to eradicate that i edited all my code still it has no improvement.. pls suggest me a solution to solve that

Comment: @Frankline, if I'm right, file.FileName is already a string. Try removing the .ToString() from your EmpdetController. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Billy u are right i removed that string and and instead of `JSON.stringfy` in my controller i used `JSON.parse(response)` and return the data. Now its working the image is getting displayed. thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Frankline Good to hear that! I would appreciate it if you could accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.toString()` from your function, the `FileName` property already returns a string.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile()
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Photos/") + file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        // prepare a relative path to be stored in the database and used to display later on.
        string filename = Url.Content("~/Photos/" + file.FileName);
        // save to db
        return Json(filename, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Parse the return in your controller. This should get rid of the extra quotes(") in your URL.

Answer (score 0):

**controller.js:**

```
$scope.UploadFile = function () {
    console.log('UploadFile');
    console.log($scope.Empdet.PhotoFile);
    var file = $scope.Empdet.PhotoFile;
    console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));
    var uploadUrl = '/Empdet/UploadFile';
    console.log('before file upload');
    EmployeeFactory.UploadFile(file, uploadUrl).success(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(response));
        console.log('$scope.Empdet.PhotoText');
        $scope.Empdet.PhotoText = JSON.parse(response);

    }).error(function () {
        console.log('error');
    });
    console.log('after file upload');
};
```

**EmpdetController.cs:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile()
    {
        var file = Request.Files[0];
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Photos/") + file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);

        // prepare a relative path to be stored in the database and used to display later on.
        string filename = Url.Content("~/Photos/" + file.FileName);
        // save to db
        return Json(filename, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Is this supposed to be an update to your question, or is it an answer? If the former, just update your question. If the latter, please explain what issue you found and how your edit fixes that.

Comment: @ CodeCaster This is the exact result of the above question asked by me changes that are made to code is `return Json(filename.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` is changed to `return Json(filename, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and the another modification is since i m getting path as a string instead of JSON.Stringify  changed it to `$scope.Empdet.PhotoText = JSON.parse(response);`. After this all issue has been solved and the application runs successfully.